# Comparing the Mounts in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement in ansible to compare the mount counts before and after the maintenance, for this i am using the below tasks. We need to compare the premounts and postmounts and if there is difference in the value, it should throw a message to check the host. Please advise.

```yaml
- name: Take premount counts
      shell: df -h |awk  ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l
      register: premounts

 - name: Take postmount counts
      shell: df -h |awk  ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l
      register: postmounts
```

Comment: You are unnecessarily piping too many command. Simply pipe df to awk  - df -h | awk '/tmpfs/ {cnt++} END { print cnt }'

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```yaml
      - name: Take premount counts 
        shell: df -h |awk ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l 
        register: premounts
    
      - name: Take postmount counts 
        shell: df -h |awk ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l 
        register: postmounts
    
      - debug:
          msg: 'There are difference in the mount count, check it'
        when: premounts.stdout_lines[0] | int != postmounts.stdout_lines[0] | int
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for replying me back, however when i tested this i got the message as
msg: [2].
Not sure what is the number in the braces meant for.

Comment: I modified my answer, if there are a difference between both mount counts ansible shows the message 'There are difference in the mount count, check it'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html) module. You can use this to print a message or fail as per condition.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Take premount counts
  shell: df -h |awk  ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l
  register: premounts

 - name: Take postmount counts
   shell: df -h |awk  ' NR>1{print $1}'|grep -v "tmpfs"|wc -l
   register: postmounts

- assert:
    that:
    - premounts == postmounts
    fail_msg: "Premounts: {{ premounts }} and postmounts: {{ postmounts }} do not match!"
    success_msg: "Mounts match."
```

Instead of running the `df` command and getting number of mounts, you can use the Ansible fact `ansible_mounts` to get this count also.

Example:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    premounts: "{{ ansible_mounts|count }}"

# some tasks in between

# Gather facts again
- setup:

- set_fact:
    postmounts: "{{ ansible_mounts|count }}"

- assert:
    that:
    - premounts == postmounts
    fail_msg: "Premounts: {{ premounts }} and postmounts: {{ postmounts }} do not match!"
    success_msg: "Mounts match."
```

Comment: Thanks so much Seshadri, let me go back and check about the same...

Comment: Hi Seshadri, when I use df instead of ansible_mounts, i am getting the error.

Comment: it gives me below error
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "premounts == postmounts",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "premounts & postmount do not match"
}

Comment: Hi seshadri_c, how do you write your answers to show colors? is there an easy way?

Comment: @Sasi that means that the value of `premounts` and `postmounts` does not match, so the `assert` is failing. Include the value of variables (answer updated) in the message to get clear understanding.

Comment: HI @garylopez I am using the syntax highlighting feature. I set my code blocks explicitly as: ```yml`.

Comment: Hi Seshadri, I meant the task which was used with Assert module was failing, if the mounts are not matching, at least the task should have been executed, however in my case the task was not executed instead, it showed fatal error with the above previous said message related to assert. However, i will try to modify my script with the updates you posted

Comment: If the assertion fails, the task with `assert` module *will fail* with the message given as `fail_msg`. This usually helps in identifying the host on which the condition was not met.